# Can't copy files to Start Up folder with VBS

Tags: vbscript, directory

This VBS code is for copying files. It is working perfectly, it has only one problem. I can't copy files to the start up folder. It has no error messages, it's just simply not working.

```vb
strUser = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName

source= "l2.vbs" 
destination = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp"

Dim oShell, source, destination 

Set Shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Shell.Run "xcopy.exe " & source & " " & destination & " /R /Y"
Set Shell = Nothing
```

Comment: Your destination path has a space in it, so you need to put it in quotes. Also, make sure that the working directory is what you expect when you try to copy files without a path.

Comment: When i copy it manualy then it asks for admin, and its working. But with the vbs its still not working. Also tried to add admin privileges to the script but did not help.